# Dataflow Custom metrics in Go SDK don't appear in Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are trying to expose some metrics from our dataflows and we are hoping they would be available in the gcloud Metrics, but they only appear altogether in the gcloud Logging as part of `jsonPayload.message` (a big blob of text).

For example:

```golang
beam.NewDistribution("my_dataflow_name", "processingCount")
beam.NewCounter("my_dataflow_name", "total")
```

would appear in the `jsonPayload.message` (with tons of other things):

```
"RESP: instruction_id: "-3425"
process_bundle_progress: <
  metrics: <
    ptransforms: <
      key: ""
      value: <
        user: <
          metric_name: <
            namespace: "my_dataflow_name"
            name: "processingCount"
          >
          distribution_data: <
            count: 1053
            sum: 567
            max: 2
          >
        >
         user: <
          metric_name: <
            namespace: "my_dataflow_name"
            name: "total"
          >
          distribution_data: <
            count: 1053
            sum: 155992
            min: 1
            max: 644
          >
        >
        ...
```

Are we missing something?

Per [dataflow docs in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-stackdriver-monitoring#custom_metrics):

*Any metric you define in your Apache Beam pipeline is reported by Dataflow to Monitoring as a custom metric.
...
Dataflow reports incremental updates to Monitoring approximately every 30 seconds. All user metrics are exported as a double data type to avoid conflicts. Custom metrics in Dataflow appear in Monitoring as custom.googleapis.com/dataflow/metric-name and are limited to 500 metrics per project.*

Comment: Have you enabled Stackdriver API? Additionally, please check if you are granted with "roles/monitoring.metricWriter" role which is needed to write to Stackdriver monitoring. Let me know about the results.

Comment: Hi @muscat. 
The Stackdriver API was enabled - we already use google cloud for other things in our company. 
I have granted "roles/monitoring.metricWriter" to both service accounts I believe are related to dataflow creation/execution:
  - pipeline-runner@<projectID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - service-<number>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com

But we still don't see the metrics in the "Metrics Explorer".

As a side note, we can see our metrics from gke and app engine. 

I am digging the logging, trying to find any entries that may give some light. 

Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if you find sth in the logs, it could be really helpful with finding the cause of the issue.

Comment: We have decided to use prometheus for our metrics - we already had a [Prometheus Pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) to have our metrics from app_engine. 
Anyway, thank you for your help.
We may try again beam metrics in the future.